# What is the normal force below a bloc on a tilted plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, torque, equilibrium

Suppose there's a *solid* regular rectangular bloc of mass $m$ standing still on a tilted plane (inclination angle $\theta$).  There are three forces acting on the bloc : its weight $P = m g$, the normal $N$ and a friction force $f$, as shown on the picture below:

[image]

The friction force element is $df = \mu \, dN$, where $\mu$ is a constant, and $dN = n(x) \, dx$ is the normal element at position $x$ below the bloc (coordinate $x$ is defined from the lower left corner, on the picture).  The function $n(x)$ defines the normal distribution below the bloc, which should stay in static equilibrium. From Newton's equation, we have $f = m g \sin \theta$ and $N = m g \cos \theta$.  Also:
$$\tag{1}
N = \int_0^b n(x) \, dx,
$$
where $b$ is the bloc lenght.  Since $f = \mu \, N$, we also have $\mu = \tan \theta$ (so the bloc could stay in place).  The rotation equilibrium condition implies a constraint on the function $n(x)$ ($h$ is the height of the bloc):
\begin{align}
\sum \tau &= \int_0^b df \, \frac{h}{2} - \int_0^b n(x) \, (b/2 - x)\, dx \\[2ex]
&= \frac{1}{2}(\mu h - b) N + \int_0^b n(x) \, x \: dx = 0. \tag{2}
\end{align}
This equilibrium equation imposes
$$\tag{3}
\int_0^b n(x) \, x \: dx = \frac{1}{2}(b - \mu h) N,
$$
which is positive only if $b > \mu h$, or $b/h > \tan \theta$.  We could also find the same if we assume that the full normal $N$ is located at position $x_N$ below the bloc (without considering a smooth distribution below the bloc).  Equation (3) then says that
$$\tag{4}
x_N = \frac{\int_0^N n(x) \, x \: dx}{\int_0^b n(x) \, dx} = \frac{1}{2} (b - \mu h).
$$

The question is how can we find the normal distribution below the bloc?  What is the function $n(x)$?  Something is missing in the analysis above.

Comment: There are many $n(x)$ which will satisfy translational and rotational equilibrium, which is all that you require here. Therefore, $n(x)$ is indeterminate.

Comment: @Evan, I know that $n(x)$ is not determined by the analysis above, but what are the other conditions or constraints that determines $n(x)$?  It feels weird to me that Newtonian mechanics let an arbitrary function to stay into the problem.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think that you would need to relieve the constraints somehow and specify the constitutive nature of either the block or the wedge. For example, if the block were resting on a bed of springs with specified stiffness, it may become solvable. I'll let some others chime in. I know that in soil mechanics determining something like $n(x)$ is of interest. Newtonian (rigid body) mechanics is too coarse of a model to get at the level of detail you're interested in here. You would want to look more to continuum mechanics.

Comment: The distribution of the normal force would depend on the “flatness” of the two surfaces. Three points of contact would do, with at least one of them toward the lower vertical edge.